# Rampart PostDispatchVerificationHandler: InvalidSecurity - Security policy not found

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

**Edit:**

I tweaked the Rampart configuration a little and I am now stuck at another point.

In Rampart's PostDispatchVerificationHandler an exception is thrown, because the security header hasn't been processed.

```
// If a security header is there and Rampart is engaged, it has to be processed.  
// If it is not processed, there must have been a problem in picking the policy 

SOAPHeaderBlock secHeader = getSecurityHeader(msgContext);
if (secHeader != null && (secHeader.isProcessed() == false)) {
     throw new AxisFault("InvalidSecurity - Security policy not found");
}
```

Log:

```
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=a5012f2f13095af97123a192575c50a7f727850f3a9ecfc5] Invoking Handler 'HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=a5012f2f13095af97123a192575c50a7f727850f3a9ecfc5] Invoking Handler 'Post dispatch security verification handler' in Phase 'Dispatch'
[ERROR] InvalidSecurity - Security policy not found
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: InvalidSecurity - Security policy not found
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.PostDispatchVerificationHandler.invoke(PostDispatchVerificationHandler.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.ChargepointservicesStub.getCPNInstances(ChargepointservicesStub.java:5361)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.Chargepoint.<init>(Chargepoint.java:180)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.Chargepoint.main(Chargepoint.java:81)
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=a5012f2f13095af97123a192575c50a7f727850f3a9ecfc5] Invoking flowComplete() in Phase "Dispatch"

...

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: InvalidSecurity - Security policy not found
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.PostDispatchVerificationHandler.invoke(PostDispatchVerificationHandler.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.ChargepointservicesStub.getCPNInstances(ChargepointservicesStub.java:5361)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.Chargepoint.<init>(Chargepoint.java:180)
    at webservices.chargepoint.com.dictionary.Chargepoint.main(Chargepoint.java:81)
```

That is the security header:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsu:Created>2013-12-16T23:07:03.868Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2013-12-16T23:12:03.868Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
```

That is Rampart's policy file:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:SupportingTokens>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The user credentials are set in the Java code:

```
Options options = stubWeb._getServiceClient().getOptions();
try
{
    options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,
                        loadPolicy("policy.xml"));
}
catch (XMLStreamException e1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
options.setUserName("xxx");
options.setPassword("yyy");

stubWeb._getServiceClient().setOptions(options);
stubWeb._getServiceClient().engageModule("rampart");
```

**Original Post:**

I've been googling this error for days but I am out of ideas.

The code is generated by Axis2 for a SOAP webservice based on this WSDL: https://webservices.chargepoint.com/cp_api_4.1.wsdl

With soapUI everything works well and I can also get some mock responses with my code from my local Tomcat server. 
When trying to connect to the web service with my Java client I always receive this error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header
>   http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
>   : Security

That's my code (username and password are hidden):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    log4j.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    GetCPNInstancesResponse resp = new GetCPNInstancesResponse();

    ChargepointservicesStub stubWeb = null;
    try
    {
        ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("/Users/jonas/projects/workspace_openHAB/axis2-1.6.2_clean/repository", null);   
        stubWeb = new ChargepointservicesStub(ctx);    
        GetCPNInstances cpn = new GetCPNInstances();        
        SOAPFactory sfac = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory(); 
        stubWeb._getServiceClient().engageModule("rampart");

        OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
        OMNamespace wsseNamespace = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse");
        OMElement omSecurityElement = omFactory.createOMElement("Security", wsseNamespace);
//          omSecurityElement.addAttribute("soapenv:mustUnderstand", "1", null);
//          OMNamespace soapenv = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv");
//          omSecurityElement.addAttribute("mustUnderstand", "1", soapenv);

        OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement("UsernameToken", wsseNamespace);
        OMElement omuserName = omFactory.createOMElement("Username", wsseNamespace);
        omuserName.setText("yyy");
        OMElement omPassword = omFactory.createOMElement("Password", wsseNamespace);
        omPassword.setText("xxx");
        omPassword.addAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText", null);

        omusertoken.addChild(omuserName);
        omusertoken.addChild(omPassword);
        omSecurityElement.addChild(omusertoken);

        SOAPHeaderBlock block = ElementHelper.toSOAPHeaderBlock(omSecurityElement, sfac);
        block.setMustUnderstand(true);
        stubWeb._getServiceClient().addHeader(block);

        resp = stubWeb.getCPNInstances(cpn);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That generates this request:

```
[DEBUG] >> "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>yyy</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getCPNInstances xmlns:ns1="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices" />
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

The exact same request works with soapUI.

I also receive a correct response by the server with my code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2013-10-25T16:54:30.767Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2013-10-25T16:59:30.767Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getCPNInstancesResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:dictionary:com.chargepoint.webservices">
            <CPN>
                <cpnID>1</cpnID>
                <cpnName>USA</cpnName>
                <cpnDescription>ChargePoint Operations</cpnDescription>
            </CPN>
            <CPN>
                <cpnID>2</cpnID>
                <cpnName>EU</cpnName>
                <cpnDescription>ChargePoint Europe</cpnDescription>
            </CPN>
            <CPN>
                <cpnID>3</cpnID>
                <cpnName>AU</cpnName>
                <cpnDescription>ChargePoint Australia</cpnDescription>
            </CPN>
        </ns1:getCPNInstancesResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But then the security module messes something up.

This is part of the debug log:

```
[DEBUG] XMLStreamWriter is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamWriterWrapper 
[DEBUG] Calling MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush 
[DEBUG] forceExpand: expanding element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security 
[DEBUG] forceExpand stack java.lang.Exception: Debug Stack Trace    
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:264)    
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getAttribute(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:416)   
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPHeaderBlockImpl.setAttribute(SOAPHeaderBlockImpl.java:91)    
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.soap11.SOAP11HeaderBlockImpl.setMustUnderstand(SOAP11HeaderBlockImpl.java:105)   
at chargepoint.com.dictionary.Chargepoint.main(Chargepoint.java:74)
```

When I use

> omSecurityElement.addAttribute("soapenv:mustUnderstand", "1", null);

instead of

> block.setMustUnderstand(true);

The exception above is gone and I get this error:

```
[DEBUG] serialize OutputStream optimisation: false [DEBUG] getReader [DEBUG] 
XMLStreamReader is org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.WoodstoxStreamReaderWrapper 
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv" (for attribute "mustUnderstand")  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,137] 
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)  
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.buildNext(OMDocumentImpl.java:153)  
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMDocumentImpl.java:242) 
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getChildren(OMDocumentImpl.java:204)
```

With this code the error is gone but the issue remains.

```
OMNamespace soapenv = omFactory.createOMNamespace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv");
omSecurityElement.addAttribute("mustUnderstand", "1", soapenv);
```

That are the most interesting parts from the debug log:

```
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=ca3f0db9a4fb557a33edc579a48f31508ff1f2b457c617f6] Invoking phase "Security"
[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=ca3f0db9a4fb557a33edc579a48f31508ff1f2b457c617f6] Invoking Handler 'SecurityOutHandler' in Phase 'Security'
[DEBUG] WSDoAllReceiver: enter invoke() 
[DEBUG] Signature crypto property file is not set. Property file key - signaturePropFile
[DEBUG] Signature crypto property file is not set. Property file key - signaturePropFile
[DEBUG] WSDoAllReceiver: exit invoke()

...

[DEBUG] [MessageContext: logID=ba3f0db9a4fb557a33edc579a48f31508ff1f2b457c617f6] Checking post-conditions for phase "OperationInPhase"
[DEBUG] MustUnderstand header not processed or registered as understood{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
[DEBUG] org.apache.axis2.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(mustunderstandfailed)
[ERROR] Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:105)
```

Here you can see the whole debug log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_iw7qzMyYhOSDNEMW5oOHgzY0k/edit?usp=sharing

If you have any advice how to solve that problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm guessing the h_t_t_p instead of http is not a typo but because you've too low a reputation to be allowed to post links =)

Comment: Is your rampart module engaged to the client? Could you please post your rampart policy file contents?

Comment: Hi, Rampart is engaged to the client and I also added the policy file to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I am not familiar with these technologies, but I found the Javadoc for [SOAPHeaderBlock.setProcessed](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPHeaderBlock.html#setProcessed%28%29) interesting:

"*We need to know whether all the mustUnderstand headers have been processed by the node. This will done by a specific validation handler at the end of the execution chain. For this all the handlers who process a particular header block must explicitly say that he processesd [sic] the header by calling setProcessed()*"

So maybe something like this has to happen?

```
SOAPHeaderBlock block = ElementHelper.toSOAPHeaderBlock(omSecurityElement, sfac);
block.setProcessed();
```

Another possibility can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511643/axis2rampart-must-understand-check-failed-for-header-security), where the poster changes the contents of the Rampart configuration file `META-INF/module.xml` by adding this:

```
<InFaultFlow>
    <handler name="PolicyBasedSecurityInHandler" class="org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver">
        <order phase="Security" phaseFirst="true"/>
    </handler>
    <handler name="SecurityInHandler" class="org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver">
        <order phase="Security"/>
    </handler>
    <handler name="PostDispatchVerificationHandler" class="org.apache.rampart.handler.PostDispatchVerificationHandler">
        <order phase="Dispatch" phaseLast="true"/>
    </handler>
</InFaultFlow>
```

I find this less likely to be the issue, but your problem seems so frustrating that I figured I would throw it out there.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The second solution didn't help unfortunately but now I am stuck at the point which you suspected to be going wrong in the first place. Do you suggest to modify the Rampart or Axis source code or how would you intercept the server's response?

Comment: As I said, I am a bit out of my depth here and just throwing things out there. I definitely don't think you should change the source, but check out the configuration [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200709/Journal200709.jsp#a3). Note the various configurations. Also, it seems from my searches that this error can happen if something dumb happens like trying to access the wrong URL. So make sure everything is set up as you expect--the equivalent of "Make sure the machine is plugged in" from tech support.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a solution. I had same kind of situation where i used a stub generated by wsdl2java tool. the security headers were not included when i send the requests. So i created the request using ServiceClient class and then import the policy. It looks thing like this

```
ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("clientrepo", null);

ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient(ctx, null);
sc.engageModule("rampart");   

        // create option object
Options opts = new Options();
        // setting target EPR
opts.setTo(new EndpointReference(serviceUrl);

opts.setAction("urn:something");

try {
    opts.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,
                          loadPolicy("policy.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
sc.setOptions(opts);
OMElement res = sc.sendReceive(payload);
```

And to load the policy

```
 public Policy loadPolicy(String xmlPath) throws Exception {

    StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(xmlPath);
    Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(builder.getDocumentElement());

    RampartConfig rc = new RampartConfig();
    rc.setUser(username);
    rc.setPwCbClass(PWDCallBackHandler.class.getName());

    CryptoConfig sigCryptoConfig = new CryptoConfig();
    sigCryptoConfig.setProvider("org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");

    Properties prop1 = new Properties();
    prop1.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "JKS");
    prop1.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", AppConstants.KEYSTORE);
    prop1.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password",
              password);
    sigCryptoConfig.setProp(prop1);

    rc.setSigCryptoConfig(sigCryptoConfig);
    policy.addAssertion(rc);
    return policy;
}
```